# What am I doing wrong with Django static files?

Tags: django, variables, django-templates, static-files

I am working on writing a Django app for the first time, so bear with me if I'm a little behind on things.

Here is an excerpt from my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.getcwd().replace('\\','/') + '/static'

STATIC_URL = '/static_files/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.getcwd().replace('\\','/') + '/static'
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

Note: I'm hoping that the `os.getcwd()...` line works. I am pretty sure it's not my problem, but please let me know if this is an issue. It's a placeholder for local dev purposes, so don't worry about it remaining there when I deploy.

My first issue is that template variables don't seem to be working.

An excerpt from my main template file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL|default:'/static_files/' }}css/base.css" />
```

I originally just had `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in there, but that simply returned nothing, so I tried adding `|default:'...'`. This did successfully generate the given string in the resulting HTML, but still didn't work, which brings me to my second (and more important, honestly) issue.

I can't get static files to work at all. I have tried several different methods here. I have tried putting absolute and relative paths (in various combinations) in each of the above `STATIC_*` variables, I have tried using the equivalent `MEDIA_URL` vars instead, and I have tried putting the following into my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = ('',

    # ...

    (r'^static_files/(?P<path>.*)$', 
        'serve', {
            'document_root': '/path/to/django/dir/static_files/',
            'show_indexes': True 
        }
    ),
)
```

(I grabbed the above snippet from http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/09/02/handling-static-files-django/.)

Now I should note that I will hopefully be eventually serving up static files from a parallel Apache process once initial dev is completed, but I would still really like to know what I'm doing wrong. I haven't been able to find a decently comprehensive tutorial on static files online or on StackOverflow.

All help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** In case it is important, I am on Windows 7 using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility - STATIC_URL won't be filled out in your templates unless you're passing in a RequestContext.

Make sure you have something like this in your views:

```
return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As of Django 1.3 you can also use the new shortcut:

```
return render(request, template, context)
```

Also, make sure you have 'django.core.context_processors.static' in your context processors.

---

EDIT: Possible answer to the second problem, try changing

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.getcwd().replace('\\','/') + '/static'
)
```

to

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.getcwd().replace('\\','/') + '/static',
)
```

---

EDIT 2: More possible fixes

You can delete STATICFILES_FINDERS. You only have it set to the default, so unless you intend to expand it later on, get rid of it (one less thing to go wrong).

You can also get rid of the urlpatterns entry. Not necessary.

Your STATIC_ROOT is probably incorrect. This should be the place where Django will gather all the static files from across your project (including the directories described in STATICFILES_DIRS) when you move to production.

An example from a typical settings.py of mine:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/myproject_staticfiles/'
```

That's it!

If you want to test whether Django is finding and placing your static files correctly, try running

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

In my case, that would go through my project directories, find all the static files, then copy them across to '/var/www/myproject_staticfiles/', where I can host them with apache.

The Django dev server automagically serves static files from within your project folder, so no collect_static is required while in dev. You don't even need to set STATIC_ROOT until you go into production.

Comment: That definitely fixed my first smaller problem. However, my second problem is still quite present.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did nothing for me. I'm pretty sure adding a comma doesn't change anything. It still ends up as a tuple with a single entry.

Comment: You have to be careful with lists and tuples in python, because ('foo') will iterate as ['f', 'o', 'o']. In any case, I've added some more possible fixes above.

Comment: Very good point about tuples with a single string element. I hadn't thought of that. I ultimately fixed my problem by using the MEDIA_* vars instead of the STATIC_* vars. I still gave you the checkmark because of solving my first problem and giving me a few very helpful tips. Any idea why MEDIA_* would work, but not STATIC_*?